# Timeout event in netty 4

Tags: java, sockets, netty

Hi I would like receive an event where `messageReceived` does not get called within an expected time. I tried with `ReadTimeoutHandler` where it generates exception where I can handle in `exceptionCaught()` where I would would do some work and return without closing the context. but right after that I got a bunch of exception

```
Nov 18, 2012 8:56:34 AM io.netty.channel.ChannelInitializer
WARNING: Failed to initialize a channel. Closing: [id: 0xa81de260, /127.0.0.1:59763 => /127.0.0.1:59724]
io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerLifeCycleException: io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler is not a @Sharable handler, so can't be added or removed multiple times.
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callBeforeAdd(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:629)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.addLast0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:173)
```

Am I doing correctly?

Thanks

Comment: can you share your code ? I would be interested to see what you do to handle the exception

Comment: as simple as this if ( cause instanceof ReadTimeoutException ) {
            return;
        }

Comment: From what I see it seems like you want to add the same instance of  io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler to multiple pipelines. Could that be the case ?

Comment: Ah, you give a good hint at my ChannelInitializer where I need to create new ReadTimeoutHandler for each time initChannel get called. also Is there a way to notify my final handler the channel is closed by the client?? I dont see any exception raise at the server side when the client quits.

Comment: the best way is to do some kind of heartbeats

Comment: Could you show me how to create a heartbeat event the fit into Netty async model?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are adding the same instance of io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler to many channels. Try

```
ch.pipeline()
.addLast(new ReadTimeoutHandler(3000))
```

Documentation of @Sharable:

```
/**
 * Indicates that the same instance of the annotated {@link ChannelHandler}
 * can be added to one or more {@link ChannelPipeline}s multiple times
 * without a race condition.
 * <p>
 * If this annotation is not specified, you have to create a new handler
 * instance every time you add it to a pipeline because it has unshared
 * state such as member variables.
 * <p>
 * This annotation is provided for documentation purpose, just like
 * <a href="http://www.javaconcurrencyinpractice.com/annotations/doc/">the JCIP annotations</a>.
 */
@Inherited
@Documented
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Sharable {
    // no value
}
```